# Creating Like button with jQuery and OOP PHP

Tags: php, jquery, oop

I'm trying to create a "Like" button for some articles that I'm printing out from my database. But I'm stuck.

I get to the point where I have posted my vote from the jQuery and I get an empty VAR_DUMP.

And in my OOP class I'm not sure how to print out the votes when I got them to save in the database.

Here's my code

HTML

```
   <?php
 // IF theres is a id in adress field
 //if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
$page = new CMS();
$gp = $page->getPage();


foreach ($gp as $sp) {
  //var_dump($sp);

  echo "<div class='pub'>";
  echo "<h4 class='pub-headline'>" . $sp['title'] . "</h4>"; 
  echo "<article class='pub_art'>" . $sp['content'] . "</article>";  
  echo "<p class='pub_created'>" . $sp['created'] . "</p>"; 
  echo "<p class='pub_created_by'>". $sp['writer'] ."</p>";
  echo "<button class='show'>Show</button>"; 
  echo "<button class='noshow'>Hide</button>";

  echo "<button class='btn-like'>Like</button>"; // Here  is my button

  echo "</div>";

}
?>
```

jQuery

```
  /* --------------------Selecting article----------------------*/

  // Calling for the method - likes
  $(".btn-like").on("click", like);  


 function like(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        // Declaring variables
    var id=$(id).val();
    var likes=$(".btn-like").val();


    console.log('Click Click..'); 

     $.post('classCalling4.php', {

        id: id,
        likes: likes }, 

        function(data){
            console.log(data);

            }); 

    }
```

PHP

```
   var_dump($_POST); // ***** This VAR_DUMP is getting back to me empty  


   if(isset($_POST['id'])) {

    //echo "rätt...";

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $likes = $_POST['likes'];

    $id = intval($id);
    $likes = intval($likes);


    $ul = new updateLikes();

    if($ul->updateLikes($_POST['id'], $_POST['likes'])) {

        echo "Created";
    } 
    else {

    } echo "noooo";
}
?>
```

And finally my OOP class, that is **not complete** because I'm stuck.

```
  public function updateLikes($id, $likes) {


    $stmt = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE pages SET likes = likes+1, WHERE id = $id');
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $likes, $id);

    if($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "win";
    } else {
        echo "lost";
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

At least your OOP class have some errors:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE pages SET likes = likes+1, WHERE id = $id');
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $likes, $id);
```

Should be:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE pages SET likes = likes + :likes, WHERE id = :id');
$stmt->bind_param(":likes", $likes);
$stmt->bind_param(":id", $id);
```

or if the meaning is to increase likes only by one, then:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE pages SET likes = likes + 1, WHERE id = :id');
$stmt->bind_param(":id", $id);
```

If var_dump doesn't return anything, then there might be error in the PHP code (causes error code 500 and depending on PHP settings PHP might return blank page)